# AWS :Not able to access end point from locallly running java client?

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In our organization we are using AWS for our application deployment . Application deployed into the AWS is running over https. Now i want to access some of the end point from a java desktop application which is running in my local laptop but its failing with the following error

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1172)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream.flush(ChunkedOutputStream.java:191)
        at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.flush(DeflaterOutputStream.java:282)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:194)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1690)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.close(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:188)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:79)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:557)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:438)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at com.comptel.schemas.wsdl.comptel.catalog.internal.SecurityAPIStub.login(SecurityAPIStub.java:271)
        at com.axiomsystems.activecatalog.designer.data.DataProxy.login(DataProxy.java:229)
        at com.axiomsystems.activecatalog.designer.dialogs.LoginDialog.login(LoginDialog.java:276)
        at com.axiomsystems.activecatalog.designer.dialogs.LoginDialog.okPressed(LoginDialog.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:472)
        at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3823)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3422)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
        at com.axiomsystems.activecatalog.designer.actions.LoginAction.run(LoginAction.java:68)
        at com.axiomsystems.activecatalog.designer.ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.java:32)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2322)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2200)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:495)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
        at com.axiomsystems.activecatalog.designer.Application.start(Application.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
```

In my local machine i am using below java version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

I already added certificate into the Java keystore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify inbound and outbound rules to the security group assigned to the AWS EC2 instance in which your server is running in order to allow connections to the server.

For using HTTPS, you need to add port 443 in the inbound rules with the IP address that you want to whitelist for the server(Similarly for HTTP with port 80). If you don't have a static IP, then you can whitelist all the IPs by adding 0.0.0.0/0 as shown below:

[image: Add inbound rule]
[image: Inbound rules]

You will also need to add outbound rule with your whitelisted IP(or 0.0.0.0/0 to allow all IPs).

[image: Add outbound rule]

[image: outbound rules]

You can read more about security group [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)

Comment: Is this only case when trying to access from java client not in the case of browser as browser it's working fine.

Comment: Please add your java code for more clarity.

Comment: Same Jave code working fine with other servers only issue with AWS

Comment: As I mentioned, try adding inbound and outbound rules and it should work.

Comment: Ok in AWS no need Inbound/Outbound rule if you accessing from Browser ? Its applicable only when some client try to use or Java code trying to access?

Comment: After adding this it's start throwing 403 Forbidden error from broser as well as java desktop application.